# Vim Command T on Mac not working

Tags: ruby, vim, rvm

I've compiled vim73 manually on Mac OS X Lion using xcode and ruby1.9.3 on rvm. I've compiled the C extension for command-t. When I press leader+t the command-t is opening, it is showing some files, but when I type some chars it doesn't search.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer but FWIW I had (prematurely I'm sure) given up on Command-T + Lion until I got into using the [Janus MacVim distro](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) which does sucessfully pull it down, build and integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same behaviour on my Mac. It works as soon as I :cd into a different directory. For some reason it does not work under ~/

Comment: It can take a lot of time if your ~/ has a lot of files. I have about 200GB in my ~/ and it almost seems as if VIM crashed when I use it there.

Comment: Don't know about that. All it ever indexed were Documents starting with `D`.